# Problem installing Cairo - make[3]: *** [cairo-xlib-display.lo] Error 1

Tags: homebrew

Need some help with installing Cairo Graphics using home-brew. Am I missing a step somewhere?

> 10:02:30-MaxAir@[~] $ brew install cairo
>
> Warning: Building source; cellar of cairo's bottle is /usr/local/Cellar
>   ==> Downloading http://cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.12.16.tar.xz
>   Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cairo-1.12.16.tar.xz
>   ==> ./configure --prefix=/Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.12.16_1 --enable-
>   ==> make install
>
> make[3]: *** [cairo-xlib-display.lo] Error 1
>
> make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>
> make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
>
> make: *** [install] Error 2

I managed to install Cairo manually, but that was a real pain, and not managed by home-brew.

*Update with this error
Error:

> BuildError: Failed executing: make install 
>   1. raise
>   2. ignore
>   3. backtrace
>   4. irb
>   5. shell
>   Choose an action: 3
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:10:in `raise'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:575:in`system'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Formula/cairo.rb:51:in `install'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:21:in`block in install'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:105:in `debrew'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:21:in`install'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:137:in `block in install'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:272:in`block in brew'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:613:in `block in stage'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:66:in`block in unpack'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:21:in `mktemp'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:63:in`unpack'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:56:in `stage'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171:in`stage'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:611:in `stage'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:267:in`brew'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:117:in `install'
>   /Users/MaxAir/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:186:in`'

Comment: For starters, homebrew doesn't really like it when you put it somewhere other than /usr/local, but you haven't pasted the actual error, just the error of the parent process, so it's hard to tell what actually went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. I'll try to get the actual error. Not too familiar with this.

Comment: Also, there is a bottle (binary) of cairo in homebrew that can be installed without compiling if you're on Mountain Lion or above that might save you some trouble. You can see homebrew trying it on the first line but most bottles don't support installing outside of /usr/local

Comment: if you need more detailed output of what fails. Try to install it with `brew install -d cairo`

Comment: Thanks guys!!! Will try it once I get home. Just for the record, I'm using python-igraph to build some graphs. So need Cairo if I want to plot anything. (R's igraph is working with cairo, but I don't think they are sharing the same library)